# Ограничение доступа к дате отчета о состоянии

Tags: project-management

MS Project 2013. Подскажите, возможно ли отключить функцию заполнения % по дате отчета о состоянии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эту функцию необходимо отключить для конкретных групп.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я именно MS Project тоже не видел, но скрины на ленту офиса очень похожи. Теоретически ещё какой-нибудь Sharepoint может оказаться, но подозреваю, что скорее Project.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin
Это MS Project 2013, Для создания новых меток [ms-project] необходимо иметь репутацию не ниже уровня 300. Попробуйте выбрать что-то из существующего списка меток.

Comment: These features cannot be disabled. You could customize the ribbon to remove them. But the best option is to explain to your users why these features should not be used for the projects in your group.